# Is it possible to (ab)use Picasso's downloader and cache for video?

Tags: android, caching, video, picasso, okhttp

I am writing an app which uses images and short videos (up to 6 seconds). Both media is supplied as download url and needs to be cached on the device.

For images, Picasso is doing a wonderful job, but unfortunately it cannot download, cache and display mp4 video. (As the videos are very short, streaming is not currently a requirement.)

For the moment - and you will admit this is crap -, I am downloading the video manually every time the user requests it and display it using Android's VideoView.

I noticed Picasso can be configured to use okhttp, so I added okhttp to my project and configured Picasso to use my version.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
}
```

But I've been trying - without success so far - to (ab)use Picasso to download my videos, cache them, and then hand them over to me, as I didn't find a good hook-point which isn't invasive (I want to use future versions of Picasso so I am not currently considering forking the project and rewriting it to accommodate video). What I want to avoid is using a separate downloader and cache for video.

What I am looking for is either

- a way to make Picasso download and cache the video file, and then hand it over to me for display, something like .into(new Target() {}); or
- a way to make Picasso display the video file, such as using the RequestHandlers; or
- a way to @Override Picasso's methods somewhere to accommodate the video functionality; or
- a way to use Picasso's okhttp instance (which Picasso uses for caching, as it seems) to run my videos the same way as Picasso does with images.

And ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: +Oliver Hausler , Did you got any solution to this problem ?

Comment: @ShaktiMalik - No solution with Picasso so far, sorry. I am currently downloading and caching my videos using an http client.